# Iterate nested objects dynamically and push the specific values into separate array using recursion

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, json, recursion

I am trying java script recursive function that return an array of values based on the key.

The nested JavaScript object has unknown depth. The function is working but the value are not returning properly ..I am getting only first iterated value while I am calling this recursive function  from another function. But I can able to console and see the values in same function.

Here is My json

```
{
    "id": 0,
    "name": "Root Entity",
    "children": [{
        "id": 1,
        "name": "REAT",
        "children": [{
            "id": 2,
            "name": "Business",
            "children": [{
                "id": 3,
                "name": "Region 1",
                "children": [{
                    "id": 5,
                    "name": "Area 1",
                    "children": [
                    {
                        "dealerId": 14,
                        "name": "lead 1"
                    }, 
                    {
                        "dealerId": 15,
                        "name": "lead 2"
                    }, 
                    {
                        "dealerId": 16,
                        "name": "lead 3"
                    }, 
                    {
                        "dealerId": 17,
                        "name": "lead 4"
                    }, 
                    {
                        "dealerId": 18,
                        "name": "lead 5"
                    }, 
                    {
                        "dealerId": 19,
                        "name": "lead 6"
                    }, {
                        "dealerId": 20,
                        "name": "lead 7"
                    }],
                    "kpi_1_met": 0,
                    "lead_num": 0,
                }, {
                    "id": 6,
                    "name": "Area 2",
                    "children": [{
                        "dealerId": 31
                        "name": "lead 1"
                    }] 
                }]
            }]
        }]
    }]

}
```

Here is the recursion function I have tried

```
async function outputArray(output, leadInfo, req, res) {
    let resoutput = output.children,
        constructedArray = [],
        obj = {};
        // dealerName, entityList = await entityNames(req, res);
    let leagueData = [];

    resoutput.forEach((dataArray) => {
        if (dataArray.hasOwnProperty('children') &&
            dataArray.children instanceof Array &&
            dataArray.children.length > 0) {
            // console.log("================ dataArray.children", dataArray.children[0]['name']);
            for (let i in dataArray.children) {
                obj = { 'regionId': dataArray.children[i].id, 'region': dataArray.children[i].name};
                outputArray(dataArray.children[i], leadInfo, req, res);
                leagueData.push(obj);
                // console.log("================ leagueData ===============", leagueData);
            }

        } else {
            if (dataArray.hasOwnProperty('name'))
                // console.log("================ else", dataArray.name);
        }
    });
    // console.log("================ leagueData outside =============", leagueData);
    return leagueData;
}
```

And I am calling the above recursive function in another function that is below

```
async function dataTable(output, leadInfo, req, res) {
    let obj = {},
        data = await outputArray(output, leadInfo, req, res, obj);

    // here First Iterated data only coming
    // console.log("data from data Table", data)
}
```

Output Should be

```
[ 
  { regionId: 3, areaId: 5, dealerId: 14, name: 'lead 1', region: 'Region 1', area: 'Area 1' }, 
  { regionId: 3, areaId: 5, dealerId: 31, name: 'lead 1', region: 'Region 1', area: 'Area 2' } 
]
```

It should be populated based on the hierarchy of the tree

Kindly anyone please help me on this. I am trying hard to get it out.

Comment: How you want output array? Is it like { id: 0, name: 'Root Entity' }

Comment: No it should be like 

[{ id: 0, name: 'Root Entity' }, { id: 1, name: 'REAT' } ]

Comment: I posted answer check it once.

Comment: I can't figure out how to combine the notion that you want to generate field names like `areaId`, `regionId`, and `dealer`  for various levels with the statement that "the nested JavaScript object has unknown depth."  How do you reconcile those two, given that "area", "dealer", etc. are not in the data?

Comment: @ScottSauyet  each object has id..you can see the id above the region and above the area ..and each object has name eg) " name": "Region 1"  In region 1 it has area 1 , area 2. and   Region 2 it has area 1 area2 and so on...

Its like flattening the array based on the hierarchy

Have to construct the array based on the hierarchy

if region is 1 and what are the areas, names in region 1 it should comes under region 1

Comment: Ok, I added [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59161649) based on this notion of pulling property names from strings.  I'm curious to see if it matches your goals.

Answer (score 1):

This is might you are looking for

```
let a = {
    "id": 0,
    "name": "Root Entity",
    "children": [{
        "id": 1,
        "name": "REAT",
        "children": [{
            "id": 2,
            "name": "Business",
            "children": [{
                "id": 3,
                "name": "Region 1",
                "children": [{
                    "id": 5,
                    "name": "Area 1",
                    "children": [
                    {
                        "id": 14,
                        "name": "lead 1"
                    }, 
                    {
                        "id": 15,
                        "name": "lead 2"
                    }, 
                    {
                        "id": 16,
                        "name": "lead 3"
                    }, 
                    {
                        "id": 17,
                        "name": "lead 4"
                    }, 
                    {
                        "id": 18,
                        "name": "lead 5"
                    }, 
                    {
                        "id": 19,
                        "name": "lead 6"
                    }, {
                        "id": 20,
                        "name": "lead 7"
                    }],
                    "kpi_1_met": 0,
                    "lead_num": 0,
                }, {
                    "id": 6,
                    "name": "Area 2",
                    "children": [{
                        "id": 31,
                        "name": "lead 1"
                    }] 
                }]
            }]
        }]
    }]

}


function test(data) {
            let response = [];
            if (Array.isArray(data)) {
                for (let o of data) {
                    response.push({ id: o.id, name: o.name });
                    if (o.hasOwnProperty('children') && o.children.length > 0) {
                        let child = test(o.children);
                        response = response.concat(child);
                    }
                }
            } else {
                response.push({ id: data.id, name: data.name });
                if (data.hasOwnProperty('children') && data.children.length > 0) {
                    let child = test(data.children);
                    response = response.concat(child);
                }
            }
            return response;
        }
   
        let res = test(a);
        console.log(res)
```

Comment: @Ramyachinna check in snippet

Comment: ..The values are returned from recursion but I am also getting some undefined values

[ { id: 0, name: 'Root Entity', result: 0 },
  { id: 1, name: 'SEAT', result: 0 },
  { id: 2, name: 'Business', result: 0 },
  { id: 3, name: 'Region 1', result: 0 },
  { id: 5, name: 'Area 1', result: 0 },
  { id: undefined, name: undefined, result: 0 },
  { id: undefined, name: undefined, result: 0 },
  { id: undefined, name: undefined, result: 0 },
  { id: undefined, name: undefined, result: 0 } { id: 7, name: 'Area 3', result: 0 } 
like this.. I dont know why

Comment: You can add data checks like if field data exists then only push data to response.

Comment: I need to format the output like this

[ { regionId: 3,
    areaId: 5,
    dealerId: 14,
    name: 'lead 1',
    region: 'Region 1',
    area: 'Area 1' 
  },
  { regionId: 3,
    areaId: 5,
    dealerId: 31,
    name: 'lead 1',
    region: 'Region 1',
    area: 'Area 2'
  }
]

It should be populated based on the hierarchy of the tree

Answer (score 0):

You should save result of recursive call

```
outputArray(dataArray.children[i], leadInfo, req, res);
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I get the question correctly. If you just want to iterate in the data and push that to an array the below code will help.

```
<script>
var data = {
    "id": 0,
    "name": "Root Entity",
    "children": [{
        "id": 1,
        "name": "REAT",
        "children": [{
            "id": 2,
            "name": "Business",
            "children": [{
                "id": 3,
                "name": "Region 1",
                "children": [{
                    "id": 5,
                    "name": "Area 1",
                    "children": [
                    {
                        "id": 14,
                        "name": "lead 1"
                    }, 
                    {
                        "id": 15,
                        "name": "lead 2"
                    }, 
                    {
                        "id": 16,
                        "name": "lead 3"
                    }, 
                    {
                        "id": 17,
                        "name": "lead 4"
                    }, 
                    {
                        "id": 18,
                        "name": "lead 5"
                    }, 
                    {
                        "id": 19,
                        "name": "lead 6"
                    }, {
                        "id": 20,
                        "name": "lead 7"
                    }],
                    "kpi_1_met": 0,
                    "lead_num": 0
                }, {
                    "id": 6,
                    "name": "Area 2",
                    "children": [{
                        "id": 31,
                        "name": "lead 1"
                    }] 
                }]
            }]
        }]
    }]

}
let leagueData = [];
function outputArray(output, leadInfo, req, res) {
    let resoutput = output.children,
        obj = { 'regionId': output.id, 'region': output.name};                
        leagueData.push(obj);
        if (output.hasOwnProperty('children') &&
            output.children instanceof Array &&
            output.children.length > 0) {            
            for (let i in output.children) {                
                console.log("*************** leagueData ===============", output.children[i]);
                outputArray(output.children[i], leadInfo, req, res);
            }

        }

}
 function dataTable(output, leadInfo, req, res) {
    let obj = {},
        data =  outputArray(output, leadInfo, req, res, obj);
    // here First Iterated data only coming
     console.log("data from data Table", leagueData)
} 
dataTable(data,"","","");
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not entirely clear to me if this is what you're looking for, but here is a technique that will flatten out the hierarchy, compressing ancestor name/ids into properties of the leaf nodes:

```js
const nameToKey = (name) => 
  name .replace(/\s*\d+$/, '') .toLowerCase ()

const flattenHierarchy = (node, desc = {}, {name, id, children} = node) =>
  children && children .length > 0
    ? children .flatMap (child => flattenHierarchy (child, {
        ...desc,
        [nameToKey (name)]: name,
        [nameToKey (name) + 'Id']: id
      }))
    : [{...desc, ...node}]

const data = {"children": [{"children": [{"children": [{"children": [{"children": [{"dealerId": 14, "name": "lead 1"}, {"dealerId": 15, "name": "lead 2"}, {"dealerId": 16, "name": "lead 3"}, {"dealerId": 17, "name": "lead 4"}, {"dealerId": 18, "name": "lead 5"}, {"dealerId": 19, "name": "lead 6"}, {"dealerId": 20, "name": "lead 7"}], "id": 5, "kpi_1_met": 0, "lead_num": 0, "name": "Area 1"}, {"children": [{"dealerId": 31, "name": "lead 1"}], "id": 6, "name": "Area 2"}], "id": 3, "name": "Region 1"}], "id": 2, "name": "Business"}], "id": 1, "name": "REAT"}], "id": 0, "name": "Root Entity"}

console .log (flattenHierarchy (data))
```

This generates an array of objects that look like this:

```js
  {
    "root entity": "Root Entity",
    "root entityId": 0,
    "reat": "REAT",
    "reatId": 1,
    "business": "Business",
    "businessId": 2,
    "region": "Region 1",
    "regionId": 3,
    "area": "Area 1",
    "areaId": 5,
    "dealerId": 14,
    "name": "lead 1"
  }
```

In the base case, when we're at a leaf node in the `children -> children -> children` hierarchy, we return the object we've built up with all of the leaf node's properties appended to it.  If we're not on a leaf, then we append the current name/id property to our working object, and recursively call the function on each child using this enhanced working object, then `flatMap` their results into a single array.

This does not entirely match your suggested output.  Firstly, there are more results, one for each leaf node in your input.  I'm guessing that this is fine, that you were just providing samples and not the full expected result.  If not, by what criteria do you choose the nodes to return?  Secondly, there are several additional properties from the hierarchy included here, things like `reatId` and `root entity`.  If you don't want these in the output, how do you decide to exclude them?

Finally, although I took a stab at converting the names into useful keys, it's guesswork, and it feels off.  Transforming a string data value to an object key worries me; but perhaps it's just what you want.